# What is the output of the following piece of code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(2,2):
   print(i)
```

What would happen when i=2?

Comment: Well, yes, it has nothing to print. So what is your question?

Comment: This is the sort of question you should just ask the `python` interpreter. (Afterwards, if you're still confused about what output it actually generates, even after tinkering with the code to try differnt variants & print various interim states, then perhaps ask a question here.)

Comment: What will actually happen when i=2 as there is ambiguity in for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use a `for` loop to iterate through an empty iterable, the loop is simply skipped:

```
for x in []:
    print("Hello!")
print("Goodbye!")
# does not print 'hello'
```

`range(2, 2)` produces an empty iterable: mathematically, the set of "every integer less than 2, starting at 2" contains nothing. `range(2, 2)` is not in any way ambiguous. We can see this if we do:

```
print(list(range(2, 2)))
# []
```

---

For experiments like this, you can always just open up a python interpreter (open your computer's command prompt and type `python`) and try it out. In this case, your given example (as expected) does nothing:

```
>>> for i in range(2,2):
...    print(i)
... 
>>>
```

Comment: I did execute the code which as you said printed nothing. But I couldn't figure out what is actually happening with the loop. Therefore, asked.